# Compile ctags for gvim on Windows 7(64bit)

Tags: vim, windows-7, ctags

I would like to build ctags on Windows 7 with support for custom languages. I've found some Windows builds for ctags which have support for JavaScript *or* PHP *or* CSS, but I want support for all three. I've modified the ctags source appropriately.

The problem is I don't know how to run the makefiles in Windows. There is a makefile for Borland c++ in the ctags source, but when I tried to install Borland on Windows it had some compatibility issues and refused to run the installer. I know that you can modify ctags sort of 'on the fly' by adding regular expressions to the .ctags file. I'm looking for a solution that's a little more robust than that.

Comment: Exuberant Ctags supports both PHP and JavaScript by default. CSS support and better rules for JS are usually added via the `~/.ctags` configuration file.

Comment: I know you can add support that way. I'm looking for something a little bit better though. Like the kind offered in phpctags and jsctags. Maybe the better solution here is to download phpctags and jsctags and then call them separately according to the project.

Comment: Yes, I believe that's a better approach. Be careful with jsctags, though: it's not very well maintained.